# How to align up a custom label with TabBar Item's title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have to use font icons instead of images as the icons for `UITabBar` Items.  One way I am trying to do is place a `UILabel` on each corresponding `UITabBar` Item and render them as font icons. However, `UILabel` is not align up with `UITabBar` item title. So my question is how to align up a custom `UILabel` with `UITabBarItem`'s title?

Answer (score 1):

For [UITabBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/) you can control label and image using:

[titlePositionAdjustment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarItem/imageInsets)

[imageInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarItem/imageInsets)

For example:

```
tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(10.0f, 2.0f);
tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it doesn't solve my problem. UILabel is not a TabBar Item's title, and I added this custom UILabel onto TabBar Item. I set TabBar Item's frame as UILabel's frame, but they are not aligned together vertically.

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski Thanks for  you answer it solved my problem. +1 for that